# word ifilter for docx parser error

Tags: ifilter

.Docx documents do not appear to be being indexed.

I used a unique string in a .docx, but the .docx is not returned when I search on "one".

For example here's the following text:

"Here is the text for line one and here is the text for line two."

Will be extracted via the iFilter as:

"Here is the text for line **oneand** here is the text for line two."

So when the Ifilter parses the .docx he deletes the line break separator and tries to parse "oneand here"... .

So it seems that the Word ifilter for .docx concatenates the last word of a line with the first word of the next line.

Can anyone give some ideas of how to get around this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After looking at ifilter...it seems that there are problems with the current implementation...i parse docx xml by myself to avoid such issues

Comment: Thanks Bastianneu.
Is it possible to extend the IFilter to correct this issue?
Since the IFilter works on Pdf and old versions of doc it's not a good policy to use a diferent one just for this new type.

Comment: is this a programming question?

Comment: Yes. The IFilter's GetText method returns the text without line breaks. This should be resolved with the IFilters API.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690992%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: I have the same issue, does anyone have any ideas how to sort this?

Answer (score 2):

OK I figured this one out now. Basically the 64 bit IFilter is not working correctly. It merges words that are separated by line breaks and does not carry them through. I used [Ionic.zip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) to access the docx zip archive and parsed the important xml files using a slightly modified version of [DocxToText](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/ExtractTextFromDOCXs.aspx). This works perfectly now.

Here is the modified code originally created by Jevgenij Pankov

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Ionic.Zip;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

public class DocxToText
{
    private const string ContentTypeNamespace =
        @"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types";

    private const string WordprocessingMlNamespace =
        @"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main";

    private const string DocumentXmlXPath =
        "/t:Types/t:Override[@ContentType=\"" +
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument." +
        "wordprocessingml.document.main+xml\"]";

    private const string BodyXPath = "/w:document/w:body";

    private string docxFile = "";
    private string docxFileLocation = "";

    public DocxToText(string fileName)
    {
        docxFile = fileName;
    }

    #region ExtractText()
    /// 

    /// Extracts text from the Docx file.

    /// 

    /// Extracted text.

    public string ExtractText()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(docxFile))
            throw new Exception("Input file not specified.");

        // Usually it is "/word/document.xml"


        docxFileLocation = FindDocumentXmlLocation();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(docxFileLocation))
            throw new Exception("It is not a valid Docx file.");

        return ReadDocumentXml();
    }
    #endregion

    #region FindDocumentXmlLocation()
    /// 

    /// Gets location of the "document.xml" zip entry.

    /// 

    /// Location of the "document.xml".

    private string FindDocumentXmlLocation()
    {
        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(docxFile))
        {
            foreach (ZipEntry entry in zip)
            {
                // Find "[Content_Types].xml" zip entry
                if (string.Compare(entry.FileName, "[Content_Types].xml", true) == 0)
                {
                    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                    {

                        entry.Extract(stream);
                        stream.Position = 0;

                        xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
                        xmlDoc.Load(stream);
                    }

                    //Create an XmlNamespaceManager for resolving namespaces


                    XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr =
                        new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
                    nsmgr.AddNamespace("t", ContentTypeNamespace);

                    // Find location of "document.xml"


                    XmlNode node = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(
                        DocumentXmlXPath, nsmgr);

                    if (node != null)
                    {
                        string location =
                            ((XmlElement)node).GetAttribute("PartName");
                        return location.TrimStart(new char[] { '/' });
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    #endregion

    #region ReadDocumentXml()
    /// 

    /// Reads "document.xml" zip entry.

    /// 

    /// Text containing in the document.

    private string ReadDocumentXml()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(docxFile))
        {
            foreach (ZipEntry entry in zip)
            {
                if (string.Compare(entry.FileName, docxFileLocation, true) == 0)
                {
                    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                    {

                        entry.Extract(stream);
                        stream.Position = 0;

                        xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
                        xmlDoc.Load(stream);
                    }

                    XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr =
                        new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
                    nsmgr.AddNamespace("w", WordprocessingMlNamespace);

                    XmlNode node =
                        xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(BodyXPath, nsmgr);

                    if (node == null)
                        return string.Empty;

                    sb.Append(ReadNode(node));

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
    #endregion

    #region ReadNode()
    /// 

    /// Reads content of the node and its nested childs.

    /// 

    /// XmlNode.

    /// Text containing in the node.

    private string ReadNode(XmlNode node)
    {
        if (node == null || node.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element)
            return string.Empty;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (XmlNode child in node.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (child.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element) continue;

            switch (child.LocalName)
            {
                case "t": // Text

                    sb.Append(child.InnerText.TrimEnd());

                    string space =
                        ((XmlElement)child).GetAttribute("xml:space");
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(space) &&
                        space == "preserve")
                        sb.Append(' ');

                    break;

                case "cr":                          // Carriage return

                case "br":                          // Page break

                    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    break;

                case "tab":                         // Tab

                    sb.Append("\t");
                    break;

                case "p":                           // Paragraph

                    sb.Append(ReadNode(child));
                    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    break;

                default:
                    sb.Append(ReadNode(child));
                    break;
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Here is the usage of this code...

```
DocxToText dtt = new DocxToText(filepath);
string docxText = dtt.ExtractText();
```

Answer (score 1):

Placing the cursor in the middle of a word and saving the document will result in the word being split among two XML tags, with a "_GoBack" bookmark in between.  The result is that after parsing with this routine, a space is placed between these two string fragments, instead of merging them back to one string.  It's easy enough to handle the "_GoBack" scenario, but there's probably other ones as well.  Maybe "Track Changes" and who knows what else.

Does a more detailed parsing algorithm exist for DOCX?